# How to approach creating a visual thermometer

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, controls, slider, slide

I have an `input` box in my page which represents disease thermometer values. I would like  to add a visual thermometer, so as when user inputs a value, a loading bar to fill the thermometer and if the value is big, the colour of the thermometer will change it's colour.

I found this:

http://www.fundraiserinsight.org/thermometer/

But it begins from 0 and also it is static.

Comment: It will be great to know What problem you are facing ?

Comment: What mark-up are you using, and what JavaScript have you tried? What've you researched and what went wrong in/with your implementation?

Answer (score 4):

One idea might be a slider and a therometer that changes color.  Something like http://jsfiddle.net/VNjVv/  ('run')

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is to display a different image from your referenced thermometer HTML examples according to the level of donations. And, make the images grow in size. Sorry I am not posting the actual code to accomplish this task ;-)